# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Listen on the Saved Property

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I've been searching for a solution to get noticed when a Document turned **Dirty** (Unsaved)

I know that there is a property  `Saved` on a word document but my problem is that I need to get notice when that Boolean turn to `false`. I've been searching for an event with no success.

Events that I've tried :

```
DocumentChange // this event fired when the a new document is open
WindowSelectionChange // this event fired when the carriage move but not when the document text change
```

I looked at the [Microsoft.Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application_events.aspx) event page but none of them seem to work for my case.

I'm out of solution.

**Context:**

I created a WPF application that upload the document. Inside this application I've a upload `button`. This button is disable when the `Saved` property of the document is true and I want to unable it when this flag turn to false. But there is no hook when this property change...

Comment: There isn't one, to my knowledge.  What's the wider context of this?  What are you trying to achieve?  There may be another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the [DocumentBeforeSave](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838299(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Application class. It is fired before any open document is saved.

Also you may consider using a timer object for checking the Saved property value periodically. Be aware, you need to access the Word object model on the main thread to avoid issues because Office applications uses the single threaded apartment model.

Comment: The problem with this is that the user need to save the document to enable the button I want to enable the button as soon as the text changed

Comment: Use a timer then. The Word object model doesn't provide any other event for that.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that solution but doesn't seem effective

Comment: I used the timer solution

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way you can do exactly what you want - there's no specific event, so the only thing I could think would be to check each time the selection changes (as although this fires when there is no change, it will also fire when there is a change).

Another solution, though: your WPF button is probably bound to an `ICommand` which has a `bool CanExecute()` method.  If the command's `CanExecuteChanged` event is linked to the framework's `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event, then the button should update on various events (focus change etc - whenever the framework thinks state may have changed.  It fires a lot!)

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }     
}
```

This is usually how various MVVM framework's `RelayCommand` / `DelegateCommand` implementations handle this.

Comment: I regret to tell you but it can't be aplied to the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI).

Comment: The application is independent of word